# react test jest "Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string... ..."

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

Test suite failed to run

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

my utils.test.js

npm test src/utils/tests/utils.test.js

```
import { fixedZero } from '../utils';

// fixedZero test
describe('utils', () => {
  it('fixedZero', () => {
    expect(fixedZero(0)).toBe('00');
    expect(fixedZero(5)).toBe('05');
    expect(fixedZero(10)).toBe(10);
    expect(fixedZero(55)).toBe(55);
  });
});
```

in my utils.js, I imported something from my index.js

```
import store from '../index';
```

my index.js, it works fine in the browser, but when I run my test, it did not pass

```
import '@babel/polyfill';
import 'formdata-polyfill';
import 'url-polyfill';
import dva from 'dva';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import createLoading from 'dva-loading';
import 'moment/locale/zh-cn';
import './rollbar';
import './zhuge';

import './index.less';
const app = dva({
  history: createHistory({
    basename: '',
  }),
});
app.use(createLoading());
app.model(require('./models/global').default);
app.router(require('./router').default);
app.start('#root');

export default app._store;
```

Comment: where the code to look at ? please post the code along with your question mate

Comment: @ray I don't think your issue is with your config - it looks like it's more likely in one of your tests - can you post the test code?